# getting auth.users table data in supabase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase

I created a recipes table in supabase with a foreign key of user_id inside it that is getting from supabase build in users table `auth.user.id` now I'm trying to get all the recipes with the date of the user [(user_id in recipe table)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00olM.png):

```
export async function getRecipes() {
  const { data, error } = await supabase.from("recipes").select("*,users(*)");

  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new Error("Recipes could not be loaded");
  }

  return data;
}
```

but i am getting this error  `details :  "unexpected \"u\" expecting \"sum\", \"avg\", \"count\", \"max\" or \"min\"" message :  "\"failed to parse select parameter (*,auth.users(*))`

why is that happening? how can i get the data of the user?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make requests to the `auth.users` table using the javascript library. This is not allowed as the `auth.users` table contains sensitive data and you wouldn't want this exposed to your client side code. You should create a table in your `public` schema with the data you want access to, you can take a look at this documentation page which discusses this https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/managing-user-data

Comment: but by doing this how the first and last name gets their values in the auth.users in the specific mentioned id? like if i get this table using javascript libary how then i get the data i want? if you can may you provide an example?

Comment: Please read the guide I sent, you cannot store information in the `auth.users` table, you should always create a separate table like in the example and add such data there. The `auth.users` table can be changed by Supabase if there is a change in the underlying auth implementation that requires it to, so you should not modify it's schema at no point.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is to create a `public.users` table that 'represents' some data from `auth.users`. You can do this easily using `trigger`.

As an example, I want to only have `email` and `id` on my `public.users` table because other information is not relevant.

You can copy paste this code (new query) on SQL Editor on the Supabase dashboard:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
  id uuid references auth.users not null primary key,
  email text
);
create or replace function public.handle_new_user()
returns trigger as $$
begin
  insert into public.users (id, email)
  values (new.id, new.email);
  return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql security definer;

create trigger on_new_user
after insert on auth.users for each row
execute procedure public.handle_new_user ();
```

Next, try to register a new user and you will automatically see this new user shows BOTH on `auth.users` and `public.users`. You can then request to the `public.users` table using the javascript library :)

Comment: thank you so much! but now after creating a user i see it in the ```public.users``` table but not in the ```auth.users``` table and if i have some metadata such as fullname and avatar how can i get it too in the public users table?